# Find how many x-day intervals have passed since outset and another date

Tags: sql, date

In SQL, how can I calculate how many `x`-day intervals have passed since outset date?

Consider `2023-01-11` as an example for such an "outset date". For any *subsequent* date, I want to know how many **4-day** intervals have passed since the outset date.
For example:

`2023-01-13` should return `1`, because it's the first 4-day interval.

`2023-01-18` should return `2`, because it's the second 4-day interval.

`2023-02-02` should return `6`, because it's the sixth 4-day interval.

```bash
## # January 2023
##    Su        Mo        Tu        We        Th        Fr        Sa     
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
## |1        |2        |3        |4        |5        |6        |7        |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
## |8        |9        |10       |11       |12       |13       |14       |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |*outset* |         |       |         |
## |         |         |         |<<=======|=========|=========|=======>>|
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
## |15       |16       |17       |18       |19       |20       |21       |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |       |         |         |         |
## |<<+++++++|+++++++++|+++++++++|+++++++>>|<<@@@@@@@|@@@@@@@@@|@@@@@@@@@|
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
## |22       |23       |24       |25       |26       |27       |28       |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |@@@@@@@>>|<<#######|#########|#########|#######>>|<<*******|*********|
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
## |29       |30       |31       |1        |2        |3        |4        |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## |         |         |         |         |       |         |         |
## |*********|*******>>|<<~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~>>|         |
## |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So if I have the corresponding SQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (outset_date DATE, date_of_interest DATE);

INSERT INTO my_tbl (outset_date, date_of_interest)
VALUES ('2023-01-11', '2023-01-13'),
       ('2023-01-11', '2023-01-18'),
       ('2023-01-11', '2023-02-02');
```

How can I write a select statement to get the desired output:

```sql
-- desired output
-- +──────────────+───────────────────+─────────────────────────────────+
-- | outset_date  | date_of_interest  | how_many_intervals_have_passed  |
-- +──────────────+───────────────────+─────────────────────────────────+
-- | 2023-01-11   | 2023-01-13        | 1                               |
-- | 2023-01-11   | 2023-01-18        | 2                               |
-- | 2023-01-11   | 2023-02-02        | 6                               |
-- +──────────────+───────────────────+─────────────────────────────────+
```

If there isn't an "idimoatic" SQL syntax for this, I'd opt for either *MySQL* or *PostgreSQL*. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the difference between two dates in days, you need to subtract the oldest date from the earliest one, i.e. "2023-01-13" - "2023-01-11" = 2

In your case, you need the number of days between the two dates including the first and last dates, this means you need to add 1 day to the difference in days, i.e. "2023-01-13" - "2023-01-11" + 1 = 3

To get the *4 days* interval in which a date lies, simply add 3 to the calculated date difference then perform integer division by 4. i.e. for differences (1, 2, 3, 4) it will be (4/4, 5/4, 6/4, 7/4) which equals to 1 for all.

For Postgres try the following:

```
select *,
  (date_of_interest - outset_date + 4) / 4 as expected 
from my_tbl
```

The `+ 4` here is +1 to calculate the difference between the two dates inclusively as mentioned above, and +3 to perform the integer division.

[See demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/W3NYclJS)

For MySQL, it will be `(datediff(date_of_interest, outset_date) + 4) div 4`, where div operator is used to perform the integer division.

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution for MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    outset_date, 
    date_of_interest, 
    CEIL(DATEDIFF(date_of_interest, outset_date) / 4) how_many_intervals_have_passed  
FROM my_tbl;
```

[test SQL here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/2cab6787a2e3853a06ecd6cc20418f21/)

[PostgreSQL solution](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/fe66e771bebeeede40e5838e3121b6a2/) below:

```
SELECT 
    outset_date, 
    date_of_interest, 
    CEIL((date_of_interest - outset_date)::numeric / 4) how_many_intervals_have_passed  
FROM my_tbl;
```